# Telegram app to remove multiple words from input message

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

I'm trying to create a small app that reads a chat message and echoes a filtered text

I need it to take this message:

INPUT:

```
#notthis/remove

remove this line

This one too
```

Output:

```
notthis
```

At the moment all it does is remove the second word + the first hashtag:

`"hello#hello"` which becomes  `hello`

I tried adding the `/` like this `input.split("#","/");` but all it does is crash the program.

Not asking to do the program for me, but I'd really appreciate any hints.
Thank you!

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf('182049');

const helpMessage = `
Say something to me
/start - start the bot
/help - command reference
`;

bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Hi I am echoo bot");
    ctx.reply(helpMessage);
});

bot.help((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(helpMessage)
});


bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
    let input = ctx.message.text;
    let inputArray = input.split("#");

    console.log(inputArray);
    
    let message = "";

    if (inputArray.length == 1) {
        message = "no separator";
    } else {
        inputArray.shift();
        message = inputArray.join(" ");
    }
    
    ctx.reply(message);
});


bot.launch()
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate more on how are you trying to filter the input? (e.g. removing duplicate words and/or punctuations)

Comment: I'll give you an example:


` ` ` #QTUM/USDT ️

Entry Point - 26.440

Targets: 26.545 
Leverage - 10x
Stop Loss - 25.110` ` `


all I want is the word filtered out: QTUM

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expression (regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a great way to find substrings in an unknown string, even though it might be a bit daunting to work with. You can use this [website](https://regexr.com/) to create your regex.

To find a substring starting with `#` and ending with `/`, you can use the following expression:

```
/#\w+\//g
```

This will match 1 or more word characters that are in between a `#` and a `/`.

For example:

- `#foo/` will match
- `#f/` will match
- `#/` will not match
- `#foo bar/` will not match (whitespace is not a word character)

An example JavaScript code:

```js
const regex = /#\w+\//g;

const text = "something#fooo/bar #lorem/ipsum";
const found = text.match(regex);

// For each found item, remove the first and last characters
const cleaned = found.map((a) => a.slice(1, -1));

console.log(cleaned);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf('18204DjYLa9o9Y');
const regex = /#\w+\//g;

const helpMessage = `
Say something to me
/start - start the bot
/help - command reference
`;

bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Hi I am echoo bot");
    ctx.reply(helpMessage);
})

bot.help((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(helpMessage)
})


bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
    let input = ctx.message.text;
    
    let inputArray = input.split("#");
    
    console.log(inputArray);
    

    let message = "";

   
    inputArray.shift();  
    message = inputArray.join(" ");
        
    let messageArray =  message.split("/");
    console.log(messageArray);
   
    for(let index = 0; message[index] != '/'; index++ )
    {
        ctx.reply("/ta " + message[index]);
    }
    return null

    
  })




  bot.hears("cat", (ctx) =>{
    ctx.reply("Meow");
})


bot.launch()
```

Only a little issue: if my coin has more than 3 letters it gets truncated.
For loop solves the problem but every letter starts with a new line, and the second imput gets messed up

```
Eg:   echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
E

echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
O

echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
S
```

2nd attempt:

```
echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
S

echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
O

echobot, [13.05.21 00:54]
E
```